# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Update Trigger on a table updates a single row/cell in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have to update a cell in column2 in table 2 for a specific userid (row), when they update a cell in column1 in table 1. But i keep getting the result, that the entire column in table 2 is updated. Can anyone tell me if and how this is done?

(Table1 and Table2 have a common column (userid))

Here is my attempt:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_TABLE2
   ON  dbo.TABLE1 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE dbo.TABLE2 
SET dbo.TABLE2.COLUMN2 = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.TABLE2 T2
join
dbo.TABLE1 T1
on T2.userid=T1.userid
where T2.userid=T1.userid

END
GO
```

Comment: Key point to note is that Triggers are not fired once per row inserted.  You access the inserted rows via the `inserted` table available within the context of the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you think too complex:

```
UPDATE dbo.TABLE2 
SET dbo.TABLE2.COLUMN2 = GETDATE()
where dbo.TABLE2.userid= (select userid from inserted)
```

and if you want to do it only after UPDATE, say it also:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_TABLE2
   ON  dbo.TABLE1 
AFTER UPDATE
```